# Determining current magnitude

Tags: current

Here is problem 3.9 from Hayt "Engineering Circuit Analysis".
[image: problem 3.0 Hayt]

I reduced it to single voltage source, keeping direction of current the same as indicated by arrow.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fbpdb3.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Solving it gives me current of 54A, while answer is -54A.What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

Add your voltage sources again. Have you got your V1 correct?

Comment: 4+3-5-1 = 1.  4 and 3 have the same direction and 5 and 1 have opposite direction. Would you add differently?

Comment: Aaaarrrgh! I missed the +3 V. No, you are correct. They sum to V1 = 1 V. But then where is 54 A coming from? I = V/R = 1/54 A, not 54 A. I think you can forget about that question in the book.

Comment: You are correct, I actually was too much concerned about sign of the current, rather than magnitude. Thank you!